# Dual Citizen Border Hopping to Extend Tourist Visa

Tags: tourist-visas

My 90 day Namibia tourist visa expires next month but I would like to stay longer. It is too late to apply for an extension, so it would seem that my only option is to border-hop. I am in the lucky position that I have two passports - a French one and an Canadian one. The Canadian one hasn't been used at all in Africa.

I imagine the steps for obtaining a new 90 day tourist visa would be as follows:

- Exit SA on my "used" French passport to get an exit stamp.
- Enter Namibia on my "fresh" Canadian passport.
- Stay for a few days, then leave Angola using my Canadian passport.
- Enter Namibia with my Canadian passport.

Will this succeed?

Comment: Can someone edit the question to clarify what is border-hopping?

Comment: Revision 2 of this question actually made sense. Now the body and the title are disconnected from each other, and the answer is missing the context it requires.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've restored the second version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visa is for *you as a person*, not for *your passport*. What you plan to do is equivalent to reusing the same passport, plus you are trying to sneak it by them. If they find out, it is probably a federal crime (or whatever that is called in SA), and might end in serious trouble.

Comment: South Africa does not have a Federal Government so it is just a crime, but in a higher schedule. Source: I'm a South African.